# Why does Chrome return 403 error from Azure App Gateway

Tags: google-chrome, azure-application-gateway

I have an Azure App Service sitting behind an Azure App Gateway on the WAF v2 tier. We are experiencing an issue where we get the 403 Forbidden response from the gateway in Chrome browser, yet the site displays correctly from Chrome Incognito mode, and works fine in IE and Edge.

I've tried clearing browser history/cookies/cache in Chrome but have not been able to successfully reach the site from Chrome.

The app gateway listeners are doing the SSL cert termination, and we have basic rules in place. We do have some HTTP redirect listeners and rules in place.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting Chrome or the App Gateway?

Answer (score 3):

We didn't find the reason why Chrome was blocked where IE or Edge was allowed, but we did find a solution where we found the firewall was blocking some application specific cookies and returning a 403 response.

Adding some exclusion rules for the cookies allowed Chrome to begin working.

This doc from Microsoft provided some useful information for tracking down the offending entries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/web-application-firewall-troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 403 response code means that a client is forbidden from accessing a valid URL. There are quite number of chances which might be causing the issue. I would suggest you disable all your chrome extensions and give a try. Even reinstallation of chrome should help in this way. As Incognito mode doesn’t load extensions might be the reason for loading the site.

Answer (score 0):

We were experiencing similar issue. Disabling all Chrome extensions didn't help. Clearing the browser cache did.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with the 403 error. What I ended up doing was clicking on the settings link, opened "privacy and security", clicked on  "cookies and other site data", scrolled down and clicked on "All cookies and site data" then clicked the remove all button. I had to re enter passwords and such, but I was able to access the site that was needed again